# How to start an already named screen session?

Tags: gnu-screen

I can start a screen session with:

screen "commandhere"

which will start a screen session, running the "commandhere".

**The question:** how can I name this screen session automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-S`, for example:

```
screen  -S my-new-session sleep 100
```

You can then see a new session in a list of sessions:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
26667.my-new-session    (Attached)
```